# Android application crashes when callling Intent

Tags: android

> Android application crashes when call intent

give a proper solution

```
public class InformationActivity extends Activity {

Button btn_submit;
CheckBox iz_check,bc_check,vc_check,ac_check,uc_check;
EditText no_et;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);
    btn_submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsubmit1);
    iz_check= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check1);
    bc_check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check2);
    vc_check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check3);
    ac_check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check4);
    uc_check=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check5);
    no_et=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittext7);

    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //String str = no_et.getText().toString();
            //SMSReceiver receiver = new SMSReceiver();

            Intent navigationintent = new Intent(InformationActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(navigationintent);
        }
    });

}

}
```

> Please give me a solution

code

```
package info.androidhive.slidingmenu;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import info.androidhive.slidingmenu.model.NavDrawerItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    /  /
    slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private ArrayList < NavDrawerItem > navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);
        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
        .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList < NavDrawerItem > ();
        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1)));
        // Communities, Will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "22"));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1)));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "50+"));
        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
        navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
        R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
        R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
        R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }
    /**
    * Slide menu item click listener
    * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView < ? > parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
            return true;
            default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
    /* *
    * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
    */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    /**
    * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
    * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
            case 1:
            fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
            case 2:
            fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
            case 3:
            fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
            case 4:
            fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
            case 5:
            fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }
    /**
    * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
    * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
    */
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

logcat's log:

```
01-27 14:09:49.668: D/AndroidRuntime(27312): Shutting down VM
01-27 14:09:49.668: W/dalvikvm(27312): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41625bc0)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312): Process: info.androidhive.slidingmenu, PID: 27312
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{info.androidhive.slidingmenu/info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2342)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1266)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5421)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:979)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:795)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at info.androidhive.slidingmenu.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:86)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1099)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
01-27 14:09:49.668: E/AndroidRuntime(27312):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: have you defined activity in manifest file

Comment: Added `MainActivity ` in `AndroidManifest ` or `btn_submit ` button is available in `activity_info ` layout?

Comment: Yes I did it. I checked mainifest.xml file.  on the main activity I set a Navigation drawer using material design.

Comment: match your button id of xml

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared the MainActivity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Also, please post the error log.

Comment: the problem is in your MainActivity